# Why does not changing reference work in __exit__ function?

Tags: python, list, reference, slice, contextmanager

```
import copy
class Atomic:
    def __init__(self, mutable, Shallow_copy = True):
        self.original = mutable
        self.copy = copy.copy if Shallow_copy else copy.deepcopy

    def __enter__(self):
        self.modified = self.copy(self.original)
        return self.modified
    
    
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
        if exc_type is None:
           self.original[:] = self.modified
```

So I saw this piece of code I a book and it is supposed to create a context manager that helps you to change list atomically. If there is an exception raised none of the changes will apply. Otherwise all of them will. For example:

```
try:       
    with Atomic(example_list) as atomic:
        atomic.append(5)
        atomic.pop(-2)
        atomic[3] = 6
except Exception as err:
    print(err)
```

Everything works fine like this. The thing I do not understand is the last line in **exit**:

```
self.original[:] = self.modified
```

I know that it does not change the reference, but changes values in the original list without changing reference. But why does not work this:

```
self.original = self.modified
```

It changes the reference of the original list to the modified list. So it should refer to list that is modified. But when you run the code like this (without the slicing) it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you didn't make the in-place copy. Now `self.original` refers to a different `list` object than it did previously. After running this code

```
x = [1,2,3]

y = Atomic(x)

with y as atomic:
    atomic.append(5)
    atomic.pop(-2)
    atomic[2] = 6  # No error, so the atomic operation succeeds
```

you no longer have `x` and `y.original` referring to the same list; `x == [1,2,3]`, but `y.original == [1,2,6]`.

---

Or are you not aware that `x[:] = y` in fact makes an in-place copy? `x = y` simply makes `x` refer to whatever `y` refers to, losing the reference to whatever `x` referred to previously. `x[:] = y` is more like

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i] = y[i]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, makes sense now. However I believe you have made a typo and wanted to write `with y as atomic:`

Answer (score 0):

If you assign without [:], you will change a link to this mutable object in Atomic object, but will not affect original mutable variable